# uploading video in Facebook, ¿parameters?

Tags: iphone, facebook, post

I'm uploading a video to facebook form my iphone app. More customized is better. I would like to know how many parameters I can set in params, and what are them. but i'm not able to find it, any help?

This is the function:

```
[facebook_ requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

I have "content type", "title", "description" and the video... anything else?

Comment: Nice question mark. Are you Spanish? :-) I like this.

Comment: Yes!, sorry ab my english & thank you Mat for the editing ;)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389288/post-video-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: I already saw that... There is no more options? Thank you Nikunj

Comment: Is there a way to set an image as a default when you upload a video?