# can we upload video on facebook using fbgraph api with iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Can we upload video on facebook using graph api in the iphone sdk 4.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload video through graphapi,better you use the sharekit for ios,u can download this kit .

Comment: i have used graph api to upload it .. but i  am facing crashes here with signal '0'. plz see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022472/crash-on-video-uplaod-on-facebook-from-ipod-4  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080457/problem-in-uploading-video-on-facebook-using-iphone-sdk

Comment: please go through with the memory management.I think it will solve your issue.I upload video through graph API with no errors.

Comment: @Rakesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355846/iphone-facebook-video-upload ,plese go through this link.